# What to put into applicationContext and faces-config?

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I created a JSF Application and I'm not sure what I should put into the faces-config?

One of my ManagedBeans looks like the following:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ProfileBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ProfileBean implements Serializable
```

my applicationcontext

```
<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="QuestionDao" class="code.elephant.dao.QuestionDao"></bean>

<bean id="QuestionService" class="code.elephant.service.QuestionService">
    <constructor-arg ref="QuestionDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="QuestionBean" class="controller.QuestionBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="QuestionService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="UserDao" class="code.elephant.dao.UserDao"></bean>
<bean id="UserService" class="code.elephant.service.UserService">
    <constructor-arg ref="UserDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="LoginBean" class="controller.LoginBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="UserService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ProfileBean" class="controller.ProfileBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="UserService" />
    <property name="_LoginBean" ref="LoginBean"></property>
</bean>
```

my faces-config

```
   <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
```

I saw some examples which defines `<managed-beans>` in the `java-faces.config` but I already used the `@ManagedBean` annotation in the java class. Is this rly necessary? Is my setup up with jsf spring correct? Should I also define the managed beans in the `faces-config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` that you have configured in faces-config is to make it so that you can use Spring beans instead of the old-style JSF managed beans or CDI dependency injection.

Remove the `@ManagedBean` annotation from your `ProfileBean` class. You don't need it since you are using Spring instead of JSF's old managed beans mechanism.

The `@ManagedBean` annotation is a remnant from old versions of JSF; don't use it if you are using a newer version of JSF. Current versions of JSF use CDI (the standard Java EE API for dependency injection), but you are using Spring instead, so you should configure your beans the Spring way (which you are already doing since you've defined `ProfileBean` in your Spring XML config).

Comment: Thanks, Will postconstruct and cleanup work with spring 4.0.1?

Comment: @Briefkasten yes, your bean is a regular Spring bean so Spring features like those should work like with any Spring application.

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask, when my ManagedBean uses `@SessionScoped` I'll use in my applicationcontext `<bean scope="session" .. />`. What can I use for  `@ViewScoped`? There is no `<bean scope="view" .. />`.

Comment: @Briefkasten unfortunately it looks like Spring-based JSF view scope is not available out-of-the-box; see [this open issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6543). Search a bit and you'll find some solutions on the web. For example [this one](http://rumatoest.blogspot.nl/2015/04/jsf-view-scope-for-spring-beans.html).